# Application based firewalls for Linux

Tags: linux, security, firewall

Linux has IPtables firewalls like GUFW which can block ports and IPs.

But what I need is an application based firewall like Zone Alarm and Comodo in Windows that blocks internet access to particular apps.

For example, if there is a program like Inkscape/Gimp which doesn't require the internet then I should be able to block it from accessing the internet.

Not mandatory: If possible it should show an "Allow or Deny" dialog when an app tries to connect to the internet.